# I'm only getting one record inserted in to mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have got my code working but for some reason I'm only getting one record to be inserted into the database when I do a print of the data, I'm seeing all the correct data but its just not going in to the database.  I have tried to change different parts of the code and did't make any difference so not to sure what I'm doing incorrectly, thank you in advance

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="**",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get("https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/?flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=Departures")

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()


airline_spans = resp.html.find('.SearchResultFlightListRow')
print (airline_spans)
airline_list = [span.text.split('\n') for span in airline_spans]

for flight in airline_list:
    if len(flight) == 7:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate, status = flight
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} and flight status is {status}')

    elif len(flight) == 6:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate = flight
        status = 'IDEL'
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} ')

    elif len(flight) == 5:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated = flight
        gate = 'IDEL'
        status = 'IDEL'
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'

print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate ')


sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (origin, airline, destinations, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, status) VALUES (str(From), str(to), str(flightno), str(scheduled), str(estimated), str(status), str(gate)"

val = (str(From), str(to), str(flightno), str(scheduled), str(estimated), str(status), str(gate))
#data.append(val)
print (val)


# doing a batch insert
#mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
mycursor.executemany(sql,())
mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
```

Comment: You have the SQL insert outside the for loop so it only inserts the information of the last flight in the list. Is this what you mean?

Comment: so to get them all mate where would i need to put it

Comment: @itroulli how do i fix it mate

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, I was really busy this week. I have posted my reply as an answer. Please accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest modification that would make this work is the following:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="**",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get("https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/?flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=Departures")

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()


airline_spans = resp.html.find('.SearchResultFlightListRow')
print (airline_spans)
airline_list = [span.text.split('\n') for span in airline_spans]
data = []    

for flight in airline_list:
    if len(flight) == 7:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate, status = flight
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} and flight status is {status}')

    elif len(flight) == 6:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate = flight
        status = 'IDEL'
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} ')

    elif len(flight) == 5:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated = flight
        gate = 'IDEL'
        status = 'IDEL'
        print ("This is a " + estimated)
        if estimated == "":
            print (" currently no dely ")
            print ("This is a " + estimated)
            estimated = 'IDEL'

        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate ')

    val = (str(From), str(to), str(flightno), str(scheduled), str(estimated), str(status), str(gate))
    data.append(val)

sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (origin, airline, destinations, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

# doing a batch insert
mycursor.executemany(sql, data)
mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
```